# Microwave Turntable Absorption

Tags: power-electronics, magnetics, microwave, radiation, magnetron

Do microwaves turntables absorb some microwave radiation when being used? I heard that they can act as a minimum load on the magnetron. If this is true, can I interchange microwave turntables?

Edit:
In reference to Roberts answer:
https://www.quora.com/What-plate-can-replace-a-broken-microwave-plate

Comment: If they absorb microwaves they would get hot. The ones I've used do not get hot.

Comment: No.  The material the turntables are made of does not absorb microwaves.  Keep in mind that a microwave oven works by exciting the water molecules in the food.  If there are no water molecules, or other substance that absorb the microwave radiation, then no heat is created.

Comment: Another way to say this is that the turntable is (mostly) transparent to the microwaves in the oven.

Comment: Look at a microwave popcorn bag: a carbon layer is added at bottom *specifically* to absorb microwaves and to apply more heat there to the unpopped kernels. @SteveSh BTW, not *only* water absorbs microwaves. However, glass turntables absorb very little.

Answer (score 0):

Microwave turntable are designed to absorb as little microwave energy as reasonably possible.

When operating an oven over a typical heating period the turntable may become slightly warm - but this is likely to be mainly from radiation from the food and convection from the air that has been warmed by the food.

**____________________________________**

**The following are useful comments from other users:**

Look at a microwave popcorn bag: a carbon layer is added at bottom specifically to absorb microwaves and to apply more heat there to the unpopped kernels. @SteveSh BTW, not only water absorbs microwaves. However, glass turntables absorb very little. –
DrMoishe Pippik

No. The material the turntables are made of does not absorb microwaves. Keep in mind that a microwave oven works by exciting the water molecules in the food. If there are no water molecules, or other substance that absorb the microwave radiation, then no heat is created.
Another way to say this is that the turntable is (mostly) transparent to the microwaves in the oven. –
SteveSh

If they absorb microwaves they would get hot. The ones I've used do not get hot. –
Spehro Pefhany